# Android Checkbox setOnCheckedChangeListener does not work

Tags: android, event-listener, android-checkbox

This is supposed to be something pretty straight forward but for some reason, the listener for the Checkbox does not work.

Here's my layout :

```
                <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_5"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/my_text"
                    />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/check_status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the implementation in my fragment:

```
CheckBox checkBox = mView.findViewById(R.id.check_status);
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean 
isChecked) {
                    LOGD(TAG, "IsButton checked ? "+ isChecked);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Check", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Like I said, this is something supposed to be pretty straight forward, but the listener.....well it doesn't listen anything. I'm testing on Nexus 5x Oreo and a small Motorola Marshmallow.

At some point I even tried the setOnClickListener() method:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LOGD(TAG, "IsButton checked ? "+ ((CheckBox) 
v).isChecked());
                }
            });
```

The result is the same, I don't see anything in the logcat

Does anyone have a clue as to why the Checkbox's listener is not working properly ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. I would start by verifying that your `setXXListener()` calls are actually executing. Can you confirm the checkbox is actually changing state?

Comment: @greeble31 well that's why I added logs and Toast msg. Looks like the calls are not executing and I don't know why. The logs and toasts are not called

Comment: You've logged the _listeners_, but what about the _setOnCheckedChangeListener_ and _setOnClickListener_ calls?

Comment: at what point (or where) am I supposed to log those ?

Comment: Had 2 similar activities ones and was testing in one and logging in other... Hope that's not your case :D

Comment: @makvasic I'm working in a fragment and I can confirm that the (java) snippets above are inside the concerned fragment

Comment: You could put a LOGD() before `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, for example. We must have verification that the call is actually executing.

Comment: @greeble31 you're right..I put a LOGD before the listener and it's not called/executed. There seems to be an issue in the way I handle the life cycle of the fragment. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: Restart Android Studio :) it happens to me from time to time that probably adb got broken so there's nothing in LogCat... Your code is fine so I guess AS is messing with you :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely, `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` is not being called :)

Comment: This is not an answer.

Please read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Hi @Blanc, the OP was having a problem with a listener not firing. A `OnCheckedChangeListener` will not fire unless it is registered using `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`. That is the exact cause of this problem (as indicated by the OP). This _is_ an answer, it is correct, and it requires no further explanation.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `DataBinding`, set the attribute `android:checked="@={viewModel.someState}"` and later call this listener via `ViewBinding` like

```
binding.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, _ ->
    //
}
```

`setOnCheckedChangeListener` won't be called.

1. You can set `app:checkListener` and use `BindingAdapter`:

   ```
   @BindingAdapter("app:checkListener")
   fun CheckBox.setCheckedChangeListener(listener: CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) {
       setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener)
   }
   ```
2. Or observe changes in `someState`:

   ```
   viewModel.someState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
       viewModel.changeCheckBox()
       // Other actions.
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There are few reason to not works.

1. In your xml you have to at-lease define checked type as per your requirement.

   `android:checked="false"`
2. In java file you have to required used `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`.

Hope its work for all.